# Using .find to return the year the Chiefs won the super bowl. Ive searched around and I am not sure why my code is not working

Tags: arrays

```
  const record = [    
      { year: "1971", result: "N/A"},
      { year: "1970", result: "N/A"},
      { year: "1969", result: "W"},
      { year: "1968", result: "N/A"},
      { year: "1967", result: "N/A"},
      { year: "1966", result: "L"},
      { year: "1965", result: "N/A"},
      { year: "1964", result: "N/A"},
      ];

      function superbowlWin(array) {
         array.result === 'W'
         }



         record.find(superbowlWin);
```

Using .find to return the year the Chiefs won the super bowl. Ive searched around and I am not sure why my code is not working.

Comment: you are missing `return` before the condition

Comment: I added that and it is still not working.
function superbowlWin(array) {
    array.result === 'W'
    return array.year;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
function superbowlWin(array){
    for(let item of array){
        if(item.result === "W"){
            return item.year;
        }
    }
}
```